# Scope of static inner class in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, static, scope

I am unsure about the scope of one static inner class of a non-static class.

In the lines below, would the variable DataContextCreator.Instance (part of a Singleton pattern) point to the same PDataContext instance for all Page objects/page requests or would each object have its own instance?

```
public class Page : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    private class DataContextCreator
    {
        static DataContextCreator() { }

        public static readonly PDataContext Instance = new PDataContext(TUtil.GetConnectionString());
    }

    public PDataContext DataContext
    {
        get
        {
            return DataContextCreator.Instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Do I have to work with HttpContext.Current for this to work in the desired way, i.e. no shared DataContext? If so, is there another way?

I am not sure whether modifying the static class to private (as I have done) does the trick.

Thanks!

EDIT:
This is my solution where I now have the same lazy-loading capability but without static variables. I don't think I need to put a mutex lock around the holding variable in this case.

```
    private PDataContext _DataContext;
    private PDataContext DataContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._DataContext == null)
            {
                this._DataContext = new PDataContext(TUtil.GetConnectionString());
            }
            return this._DataContext;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the code is in the page, there is no need for locking. As the property is local to the page, only one thread will access it.

Answer (score 2):

It would be the same for every page. A static variable is a static variable, however nested it is. (Generics make things "interesting" in that a static variable in `Foo<int>` is separate to the one in `Foo<string>` etc, but that's not relevant here.)

If you want to make something depend on the instance of the `Page`, it needs to be an instance variable within `Page`. (I'd advise against naming a case the same as its base class, by the way.)

Comment: Thank you. I just now see that it would be easy to do this with an instance variable. I came from the singleton pattern. But that is not required here.

Comment: And yes and I do not usually name the derived class after the base class. It is an existing class and was done by someone else. Maybe not too late to change that.

Comment: Maybe someone could take a quick look at my solution in the latest edit and post if there are any problems with it.

Comment: The new code seems reasonable so long as only one thread is going to be using the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Nested classes are purely for naming convenience (and some modifier changes (private etc)). They are actually the same as regular (top-level) classes in terms of behaviour. So  `Instance` is shared completely (it is not tied to an Page instance).

Answer (score 1):

As the `Instance` variable is static, it only exists once, so all threads share the same value. Putting the variable in another class doesn't change how a static variable works.

To make a singleton that is local to the page instance, you would store the reference in the page context:

```
public PDataContext DataContext {
   get {
      PDataContext result = HttpContext.Current["PData"];
      if (result == null) {
         result = new PDataContext(TUtil.GetConnectionString());
         HttpContext.Current["PData"] = result;
      }
      return result;
   }
}
```